# Can I reflect changes in header file in executables if i have only .o files for the dependent programs

Tags: c++, templates, linker, g++, header-files

I have two files

main.cpp

```
#include<iostream>  
#include "tmp1.h"
using namespace std;

int main() {   
cout<<factorial<7>::value<<endl;  
}
```

and 
tmp1.h

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;  
template <unsigned n>  
struct factorial
{  
    enum { value = n * factorial<n-1>::value };  
};  

template <>  
struct factorial<0>  
{  
    enum { value = 1 };  
};
```

I compile main.cpp using -c flag
  g++ -c main.cpp to generate main.o file

Then I change the base case of factorial template to "value = 2" and link it using
g++ -o tmpex main.o tmp1.h

But when I run the executable it outputs 5040 instead of 10080 which is the new value that I need.

Is there something I can do so that even if I have only main.o file and not its source code I can change header files and reflect the changes in the new executable

Summary

I have a main.o file and the header that it depends on. I want to make changes in the header files and reflect the changes in the new executable without needing the main.cpp file

Comment: No, you can't. You have to recompile everything.

Comment: header files are syntactically substituted where they are #included by the preprocessor before compilation.   They are not used after that.  You could literally copy/paste in the header file each spot where it is #included and get the same results.   Changing it afterwards wouldn't change the resulting text files that were already compiled.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, you can't.
The template is instantiated during the **compilation** phase, that is when you generate the .o file.
Adding the header to the linking phase won't have any effect